# i have task in which i want to access local mysql database from SERVER

Tags: php, mysql, database

i want to access local mysql database  from SERVER using php.

My client has an offline product database for a high street shop that they update fairly frequently for their own purposes. They are now creating an online store which they want to use product information from this database.

Migrating the database to a hosted server and abandoning the offline database is not an option due to their current legacy software set up.

So my question is: how can I get the information from their offline database to an online database? Their local server is always connected to the internet so is it possible to create a script on the website that somehow grabs the data from their server and imports it into the online server? If this ran every 24 hours it would be perfect. But is it even possible? And if so how would I do it?

The only other option I can think of is to manually upload the database after every update, but this isn't really a viable idea.

Comment: If you want to try and replicate this, there's a number of solutions, but it depends on what the two systems are doing with the data. The quick-and-dirty solution is to `mysqldump` on the master, copy it to the external system, and restore it, doing that all on an automatic schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to save the data in both local and server you have to make some changes in your php codes if you don't want to manually upload the database every time you make changes. Create two db connections in your website

```
$cn1=mysql_connect('server1','user','pass');    //for localhost
$cn2=mysql_connect('server2','user','pass');    //for server

$db1=mysql_select_db('table1',cn1);    //for localhost
$db2=mysql_select_db('table2',cn1);    //for server

$res1=mysql_query('your query', $db1);    //for localhost
$res2=mysql_query('your query', $db2);    //for server
```

The connect() and select_db() is only required once in your connect.php file or where ever you made dab cnnection. query() will have to be written every time when you require to insert, update or delete. For select you can use localhost since both data in localhost and server are the same.

I hope this is what you need...